# Date Parsing Practice

Tags: python

> Problem:
>
> Write a program to read dates from input, one date per line. Each date's format must be as follows: March 1, 1990. Any date not following that format is incorrect and should be ignored. The input ends with -1 on a line alone. Output each correct date as: 3/1/1990.
>
> Hint: Use string[start:end] to get a substring when parsing the string and extracting the date. Use the split() method to break the input into tokens.
>
> Ex: If the input is:
>
> ```
> March 1, 1990
> April 2 1995
> 7/15/20
> December 13, 2003
> -1
> ```
>
> then the output is:
>
> ```
> 3/1/1990
> 12/13/2003
> ```

My code so far:

```
def get_month_as_int(monthString):

    if monthString == 'January':
        month_int = 1
    elif monthString == 'February':
        month_int = 2
    elif monthString == 'March':
        month_int = 3
    elif monthString == 'April':
        month_int = 4
    elif monthString == 'May':
        month_int = 5
    elif monthString == 'June':
        month_int = 6
    elif monthString == 'July':
        month_int = 7
    elif monthString == 'August':
        month_int = 8
    elif monthString == 'September':
        month_int = 9
    elif monthString == 'October':
        month_int = 10
    elif monthString == 'November':
        month_int = 11
    elif monthString == 'December':
        month_int = 12
    else:
        month_int = 0

    return month_int


monthString = input()

# TODO: Read dates from input, parse the dates to find the one
#       in the correct format, and output in m/d/yyyy format
user_string = monthString.split()

monthString = user_string[0]

while monthString in get_month_as_int(monthString):
    if monthString == get_month_as_int(monthString):
        if user_string[1][-1] == ",":
            print("{}/{}/{}".format(get_month_as_int(monthString), user_string[1][-2:], user_string[2]))
    user_string = user_string.split()
    if user_string[0] == -1:
        break
    else:
        break
```

Right now I'm getting a `TypeError` stating `argument of type 'int' is not iterable`.

And I can't use the `datetime` function in this case.

Comment: get_month_as_int(monthString) returns an `int`. You are using `in` on an `int`, and `in` can only be used on an iterable, which `int` is not, hence your error.

Comment: also, since `monthString` is a string, and `get_month_as_int(monthString)` is an int, they will never be ==.

Comment: you don't need so many checks, you just need to check if the result from `get_month_as_int` is 0 in order to see if the month is valid.

Comment: also, user_string is already pre-split, splitting it again doesn't do anything for you unless you split it by a different value, eg (",")

Comment: and checking for exact values like "-1" doesn't help you if the test input changes, your program has to work for all inputs

Comment: and also you should probably use a dict for the month string-to-int conversion rather than so many elifs.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: And please provide a runnable [mre] that others can use.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_month_as_int(monthString):

    if monthString == 'January':
        month_int = 1
    elif monthString == 'February':
        month_int = 2
    elif monthString == 'March':
        month_int = 3
    elif monthString == 'April':
        month_int = 4
    elif monthString == 'May':
        month_int = 5
    elif monthString == 'June':
        month_int = 6
    elif monthString == 'July':
        month_int = 7
    elif monthString == 'August':
        month_int = 8
    elif monthString == 'September':
        month_int = 9
    elif monthString == 'October':
        month_int = 10
    elif monthString == 'November':
        month_int = 11
    elif monthString == 'December':
        month_int = 12
    else:
        month_int = 0

    return month_int


for monthString in iter(input):
    if(monthString == "-1"):
        break

    month = get_month_as_int(monthString.split()[0])
    print("{}/{}/{}".format(month,
                            monthString.split()[1].replace(',', ''), monthString.split()[2]))
    pass
```

Your original code was very close but your input logic was slightly flawed and it was not not allowing the input to continue. Here I have addressed that issue by using the iter() function https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_iter.asp to handle the input. Another issue was handling the comma in the input which I cleaned up using the .replace() function.

Comment: It's stating that x is not defined. Would x represent the input? I'm not to familiar with the iter method. You mind explaining that?

Comment: Please edit your answer to include words that explain how it fixes the OPs problem.

Comment: This is clearly a homework question, so posting complete code isn't helpful to the OP because A. it doesn't help them learn and B. It may be helping them cheat. see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions and consider explaining what is wrong without posting a code dump

Comment: @koolin The 'x' was left over from my testing and can be removed. See the edit.

Comment: @Esther It most likely is a homework question. My edit of the original code was not far from the original in logic. The primary difference being the use of iter() to handle input rather than a while loop, which OP might not have known existed. so I didn't feel it was hindering the OPs learning in any way.

Comment: @Esther It is OP's responsibility to take the information from my response and understand why it works as opposed to why theirs did not. I do not expect OP to will the correct solution into existence just because they struggled with it for a lengthy amount of time. The level of this problem shows that OP is a beginner and that they most likely do not know the ins and outs of Python or for that matter, what to Google. This is no different than developers Googling errors or solutions. You take answers provided by others and apply it to your understanding. OP is allowed to be a beginner.

Comment: @Esther sheeeesh tough crowd. I'm in a intro to python class and this question just made me super confused on how to approach it. The get_month_as_int was prefilled in the question so I didn't type any of that code. My job was only to complete it.

Comment: @TrayDenney that link helped a bit with understanding iter because it wasn't in the studies I have. I'm still getting an error but I'll play around with it. Thanks again for your patience. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
months = {
    "January": 1,
    "February": 2,
    "March": 3,
    "April": 4,
    "May": 5,
    "June": 6,
    "July": 7,
    "August": 8,
    "September": 9,
    "October": 10,
    "November": 11,
    "December": 12,
}

import re
for data in ['March 1, 1990', 'April 2 1995', '7/15/20', 'December 13, 2003', -1]:
    if data == -1:
        break
    if re.match(r'(\w+) (\d{1,2}), (\d{4})', data) == None:
        continue
    output = data.split(" ")
    output[0] = str(months[output[0]])
    output[1] = output[1].replace(",", "")
    print("/".join(output))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try to get all inputs first and then select the ones that are in the right format. This code does the work:**

```
 def get_month_as_int(monthString):
    
        if monthString == 'January':
            month_int = 1
        elif monthString == 'February':
            month_int = 2
        elif monthString == 'March':
            month_int = 3
        elif monthString == 'April':
            month_int = 4
        elif monthString == 'May':
            month_int = 5
        elif monthString == 'June':
            month_int = 6
        elif monthString == 'July':
            month_int = 7
        elif monthString == 'August':
            month_int = 8
        elif monthString == 'September':
            month_int = 9
        elif monthString == 'October':
            month_int = 10
        elif monthString == 'November':
            month_int = 11
        elif monthString == 'December':
            month_int = 12
        else:
            month_int = 0
    
        return month_int
    
    
    user_string = input()
    
    # TODO: Read dates from input, parse the dates to find the one
    #       in the correct format, and output in m/d/yyyy format
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        cont=[]
        while user_string != '-1':
            cont.append(user_string)
            user_string = input()
    
        cont2=[]
        for i in cont:
            if len(i.split()) > 1:
                if ',' in i.split()[1]:
                    print('{}/{}/{}'.format(get_month_as_int(i.split()[0]),i.split()[1][:-1],i.split()[2]))
```